# How to add a constructor to an existing class in Dart?

Tags: class, constructor, dart

I'd like to make some convenience/factory constructors for a few common UI classes. For example, TextStyle:

```
enum Font {
  AvenirNext,
  AvenirNextCondensed
}

enum Weight {
  Regular,
  Medium,
  DemiBold,
  Bold
}

// Use:
// TextStyle(Fonts.AvenirNext, Weight.Medium, 20, Colors.white)

// Maybe it can be even shorter?
// TextStyle(AvenirNext, Medium, 20, Colors.black)
```

How to go about this in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about extending TextStyle like below

```
class Font {
  static const AvenirNext = 'AvenirNext';
  static const AvenirNextCondensed = 'AvenirNextCondensed';
}

class Weight{
  static const Regular = FontWeight.w400;
  static const Medium = FontWeight.w500;
  static const DemiBold = FontWeight.w700;
  static const Bold = FontWeight.w900;
}

class CTextStyle extends TextStyle {
  CTextStyle(String f, FontWeight w, num s, Color c)
      : super(
          fontFamily: f,
          fontWeight: w,
          fontSize: s.toDouble(),
          color: c);
  }
}
```

usage:

```
TextStyle myCustom = CTextStyle(Font.AvenirNext, Weight.Medium, 20, Colors.black);
```

Comment: Alternatively, don't even make a class, and just define top-level factory functions that create a `TextStyle` object.

Comment: Yes , great. I was trying to explain that we can not modify the class .we can only extend it.

Comment: This is great. For sake of academics, what if I kept the enums and constructed an argument list for the super constructor:

`class TSExt extends TextStyle {
  //TSExt(Font font, Weight weight, double fontSize, Color color) : super(arguments);
  TSExt(Font font, Weight weight, double fontSize, Color color){
    var args = {
      // ...
    };
    super(args);
  }
}`

Comment: @GoldenJow It seems a good idea , if you tested this approch please, let us know